# Print the rows start with a string in awk

Tags: sh

For example:

```
Event .123232434
1232323 Event
1233 Event 234
Event 2323
```

I just want to the rows start with "Event" through awk

is there some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just:

```
 /^Event/
```

A rule that isn't associated with any code prints every line that matches.

As *paxdiablo* pointed out, you could also use `grep` in this case:

```
grep '^Event'
```

---

If you want to read the input from a file, this becomes

```
awk '/^Event/' /path/to/file
```

or

```
grep '^Event' /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `awk` for this, you can just use:

```
grep '^[^0-9]' inputfilename
```

That will give you all lines that start with a character that *isn't* a digit.

If you *must* use `awk`, it has an equivalent variant:

```
awk '$0 ~ /^[^0-9]/' inputfilename
```